# VBA pass the name of activesheet to a function

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have created a function to receive three parameters.:

- An array of strings
- A worksheet name
- An index for the array of strings

When I compile I am getting a compile error stating:

Compile Error:
Expected:=

My call is:

```
Sub C_Button_ImportBOM_Click()

  Dim strFilePathName As String
  Dim strFileLine As String
  Dim v As Variant
  Dim RowIndex As Long
  Dim mySheet As Worksheet

  ActiveSheet.Name = "Import"

  mySheet = Worksheets("Import")

  strFilePathName = ImportFilePicker

  v = QuickRead(strFilePathName)
  For RowIndex = 0 To UBound(v)
    PopulateNewLine (v(RowIndex), mySheet, RowIndex)
  Next

End Sub
```

The function declaration is:

```
Function PopulateNewLine(SourceString As String, ImportSheet As Worksheet, CurrentRow As Long)
```

I have tried many things to no avail. Initially with just the first argument declared and used this worked okay.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Excel 2010 VBA

Comment: I'm not sure about your compile error, but you need to use `Set`, as in `Set mySheet = Worksheets("Import")`. Is the error on `PopulateNewLine (v(RowIndex), mySheet, RowIndex)`?

Comment: Doug,
Thanks for getting back to me. Yes, the error is on that function call.

Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your function like a subroutine, i.e., you're not returning a value from it and assigning it to a variable, as you'd normally do with a function. That means you need to call it without the parentheses surrounding the arguments:

```
PopulateNewLine v(RowIndex), mySheet, RowIndex
```

If you really aren't returning anything from it, you should probably turn it into a Sub for clarity's sake:

```
Sub PopulateNewLine(SourceString As String, ImportSheet As Worksheet, CurrentRow As Long)
... your code here
End Sub
```

On another note, you should qualify your mySheet reference, and as I mentioned in the comments, use `Set`. It should look something like:

```
Set mySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Import")
```

Substitute whatever workbook Import is in for `ActiveWorkbook` above.

Comment: thanks Doug, I'll try this again. I did have the function returning an integer (success flag) but that was still giving a problem... will try it now. :)

Comment: Well making it a Sub had basically the same issue but I noticed that I had the receiving variable defined as a String but the sending variable as a Variant.

This has moved the problem down into my PopulateNewLine function as a different error.

Comment: So, did my answer eliminate the compile error message that you posted about? I encourage you to avoid questions that become moving targets. If you do modify the question, you'll want to make sure to do it as methodically as possible.

Comment: Doug,
The problem was related to the types. Passing a type variant to a type String... Don't know how I missed that. Still have problems but these are different and I will try to work through them before asking for help.

Thanks for being there. :)

Steve.

Comment: You are welcome, but I disagree. That compile error is related to calling with parentheses when not needed, not with the arguments it is called with. I copied your code and got the compile error you posted about. When I removed the parentheses, as in the second line of my answer, the compile error went away. Sorry if this seems argumentative. Usually I wouldn't pursue it to this extent, but I knmow this to be true.

Comment: Doug, not argumentative at all and I appreciate your help.

My background in coding goes back to the mid 80s when I was writing stuff in C but stopped before I got into any OO stuff or these new-fangled IDEs (which are horrible).

I decided to try this program in VBA to reduce the workload but it just feels horrible as I am trying to learn too much stuff whilst unlearning old stuff, the end result is confusion on my part.

Anyway, I'm going to try this in C# now as, maybe, I then can focus on learning the differences from C and the OO stuff.  VBA feels so clumsy.

Steve. :)